# Having trouble overriding phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p1

I'm trying to override the COA-search.phtml file found in vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates

```
<div>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;">Search for a Certificate of Analysis by Lot Number below:</p> 
    <div>
        <form action="/technical-support/certificate-of-analysis.html" method="get" name="search">
            <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
            <div class="actions" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <button class="action primary" title="Search" type="submit" aria-label="Search">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
                $documentRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                $filename = $_GET['keyword'];
                $filepath = $documentRoot."/COA/".$filename.".pdf";
                if(file_exists($filepath)){
                    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
                        echo "<p><img src='/pub/media/images/etc/pdf.jpg' alt='PDF'><a href='/COA/$filename.pdf' title='Certificate of Analysis' target='_blank'>$filename</a></p>";
                    }else{
                        echo "Certificate of Analysis found, please <a href='/customer/account/login/' title='login'>login</a> or <a href='/customer/account/create/' title='register'>register</a> to access the Certificate of Analysis.";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<p>Certificate of Analysis for Lot Number $filename does not exist or not available at this time. Please contact <a href='mailto:info@sciencellonline.com' title='Email sales'>info@sciencellonline.com</a> for further assistance.</p>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my app/code folder I have place this newer phtml file in the app/code/Sciencell/COAs/view/frontend/templates

I have a registration.php file app/code/Sciencell/COAs

```
<?php /**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register( \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Sciencell_COAs',
__DIR__
);
```

I have a module.xml in app/code/Sciencell/COAs/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sciencell_COAs" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Newsletter"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And finally a newsletter_manage_index.xml in my app/code/Sciencell/COAs/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Newsletter" name="customer_newsletter" cacheable="false" template="Sciencell_COAs::COA_search.phtml">
                <container name="customer.newsletter.form.before" as="form_before" label="Newsletter Subscription Form Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I can see the module is enabled in the config.php file. So what am I missing? Why are the changes not being reflected. I've tried it all. bin/magento setup:upgrade, compile, deploy, reindex, cache. I've also tried deleting folders rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml pub/static/frontend var/cache var/composer_home/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ generated/ generated/*

Answer (score 0):

**Change `newsletter_manage_index.xml` file with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_newsletter" template="Sciencell_COAs::COA_search.phtml">
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but It didn't work. How important is the naming convention for the xml file? I changed it to default.xml. I checked on my admin page for the block I want to override. Its called 'coa-search' so I changed the referenceBlock name to that instead of "customer_newsletter?" Also what value should go into handle in the update tag?

Comment: I'm not sure how the COA_search.phtml file in the vendor was created. But when I used your xml to override the subscribe.phtml. It worked. How do you figure out what the referenceBlock name is?

Comment: The block you want to override should be taken as referenceBlock while overriding the phtml file in custom module. If you find the solution then accept the solution. Thanks